# Звук при добавлении нового поста ВК

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно реализовать звуковое оповещение лично для меня, при добавлении нового поста ВК паблике. То есть, у меня постоянно открыта страница паблика и допустим скрипт в greasemonkey.
Нашел в интернете подобное решение, звук при появлении нового элемента. Но для постов оно не подходит. Может кто-то направить меня в нужном направлении? Куда смотреть и что искать? А то я уже совсем запутался, ничего похожего не могу найти...

```html
if (location.hostname == 'vk.com') 
audio = new Audio
audio.src = "ОТСЮДА ТАЩУ МЕЛОДИЮ"

observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
audio.play()
return false;
})
})

window.onload = function(){
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true})
}
```

Comment: есть же vk api https://new.vk.com/dev/methods

Comment: Чёт не пойму как через ВК-api в JS это реализовать можно...

Comment: очевидно, что надо еще немного почитать https://new.vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK

Comment: Всё равно не пойму. Нет, api это наверное всё не то. Группы то чужие и их много. Мне нужно просто сигнал по появлению поста...

Comment: У вас включён новый дизайн ВК?

Answer (score 1):

## no JS

Не знаю, как в старом дизайне, но в новом дизайне ВК можно подписаться на Уведомления в группе: кликните многоточие и выберите «Получать уведомления»

[image: получать уведомления]

Убедитесь, что в настройках уведомлений (сверху колокольчик - Настройки) у вас включены пункты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, дизайн новый. Спасибо! Это мне подходит!) Звук правда тихий будет, но как звук заменить это я знаю)

Comment: Вот блин! Оно работает только с записями от имени группы...

Comment: Тогда придётся писать скрипт, который забирает записи со стены групп раз в N секунд, и смотрит, изменилось ли что со времени предыдущей проверки – тогда тревога. Курите [`wall.get()`](https://new.vk.com/dev/wall.get), забирайте, скажем, 10 последних записей, смотрите на их id. Не обязательно держать открытыми страницы этих групп. Лучше сделайте одного [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)'а, и держите просто браузер открытым.